# Coffeescript/Javascript variable scope

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm not really sure why i do not have access to the @date (this.date) variable from the context of the anonymous function defined in C.f()

```
class C
  constructor: () ->
    @date = new Date()

  f: () ->
    $(document).keydown( (e) ->
      alert(@date)
    )
```

Could someone comment on that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is happening because inside the `keydown` event handler, the `this` value will not refer to your object, it will refer to the DOM element.

For that purpose, you can use `=>` (the [fat arrow](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#fat_arrow)), that will bind the handler's `this` value to the parent `this`:

```
class C
  constructor: () ->
    @date = new Date()

  f: () ->
    $(document).keydown( (e) =>
      alert(@date)
    )
```