# Getting class instance back on jquery.ajax callback

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I am trying to get a jQuery.ajax to call back to the calling instance to process messages.  However,  I cannot get the calling instance into the function.

In the GetHistory call, a list of messages are returned and I want the Process method to act on each one.  The problem is that during the callback function execution an error is returned stating "this.Process is undefined".  This is why I am guessing the instance is not being set.

I also tried adding the parameter to .ajax of 'context:this', but that didn't seem to help.

```
class MessageHandler

  @messages: []

  Process: (message) ->
      messages.push message

  GetHistory: ->    
    jQuery.ajax url:'/home/BidDetail', dataType: 'json', data: 'auctionId=1', success:     (data) ->
      @Process record for record in data.records when record.type == 'BID'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using => (the [fat arrow](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#fat_arrow)) as suggested in [Coffeescript/Javascript variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7062223/coffeescript-javascript-variable-scope)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that `context: this` doesn't work. You should be able to either use that, or use `=>` as Paul suggests (most succinct), or use the classic `self = this` (more efficient):

```
GetHistory: ->    
  self = this
  jQuery.ajax url:'/home/BidDetail', dataType: 'json', data: 'auctionId=1', success: (data) ->
    self.Process record for record in data.records when record.type == 'BID'
```

Note that I'm assuming that you're calling `GetHistory` with the syntax `obj.GetHistory()`, where `obj` is the object that you want `this` to point to in the `success` callback. You might want to define `GetHistory` with `=>` instead of `->` so that, even if you detach it from the class instance, the context will still be the same.

Comment: thanks - I was thinking that 'this' being in the context of the ajax callback would be different.

Comment: @S. Hebert Er, it is. Sorry, I've corrected the code in my answer.